# how to make record rule for asset?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have asset module .I have inherited asset code there i will assign user . if i have two companies for two user how to make record rule for company wise asset 
if A company assigned to A user 
and B company assigned to B user

I have asset inherited class and **company_id1** as company name

when A user logins he should get only A company asset or A user asset same thing for B

```
class asset_asset(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "asset.asset"
    #_name = "asset_asset"
    _rec_name= "folio_num"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Asset Name', size=64),
        'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', required=True),
        'place1': fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation', 'Location'),
        'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection',select=True, required=True),
            'area_id' : fields.many2one('asset.name', 'Asset Name Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=', asset_catg_id)]", select=True, required=True),
        'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model Code',domain="[('area_id', '=', area_id)]",),
        'folio_num' : fields.char('Folio No',),
        'asse_line':fields.one2many('asset.line','emp_id','Name Plate'),
        'asse_line2':fields.one2many('asset.part','emp_id1','Parts'),
               #'assed_modelid':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model ID',select=True, required=True),
        'quantity': fields.char('Quantity',size=64),
        'uom': fields.char('Uinit of Measure',size=64),
        'model_no' : fields.char('Model', size=64),

        #'asset_id':fields.many2one('agile.portfolio','Asset ID'),

    }
```

I need complete code i.e .xml or record rule with explanation

Comment: have you checked https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html#record-rules 
https://doc.odoo.com/trunk/server/04_security#administration
?

Comment: please help me any one

Answer (score 0):

**Setting up rules' Access Right in xml,csv files**

I created new module depends on Project Management, i want to add new Groups,users,rules and Access controls in security folder. I successfully added groups and users, and for some extend Access Controls.

**My Question is:** how to specify the access right(Read/Write/Create/Delete) for every rule?.

For example:

1.User can create/read/write tasks (ACL)

2.User can read/modify only tasks assigned to him (Rule)

3.Project managers can see all tasks in their projects (Rule)

For example:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="ir_values_my_costume_rule">
    <field name="name">My Rule Name</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_your_model_name"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('field','operator','value'),('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

You must pass model_ before model name in  like this: model_sale_order or model_project_task.

Here in eval you can either pass True or False as per you need.

Record Rules can be defined from the menu also without creating any file : Settings->Technical->Security->Record Rules.

There are three main fields that you need to configure carefully in order to define "Record Rule"

**Object:** On which you want to apply record rule. (in this example it is "Task" object).

**Domain**: Setup domain for filtering the data.
**Groups:** Add group for which you want to apply this record rule. If nothing to add then this rule is apply globally which is usually used to configuring multi-company record rule.
I am going to explain such access rule by taking the example of "Task" object of OpenERP.

In my example, suppose my requirement is like this:

The user 'rch' can access only list of tasks of following kind...

list of all tasks which is not assigned to any user. i.e.('user_id','=',False)

list of all tasks Which is assigned to user 'rch'. i.e.('user_id','=',user.id)

list of all tasks of all the project's for which he is a member of. i.e.('project_id.members','in', [user.id])

list of all tasks of the project for which he is a project manager. i.e.('project_id.user_id','=',user.id)

**Configure your record rule as follow:**

Name: Tasks According to User and Project.

Object: Task.

Domain: ['|','|','|',('user_id','=',False),('user_id','=',user.id),('project_id.members','in', [user.id]),('project_id.user_id','=',user.id)].

Groups: project/User.

Now add this group (project/User) to user 'rch'.

Answer (score -1):

Go to ->

- Setting

  - Technical

    - Security

      - Record Rule
        Create new rule for assets.

Uncheck all the access rights for read, write, create and delete.
[image]

Comment: i am not able click on global check box

Comment: its not workin in one instance but in other instance its working fine

Comment: not require to click on global check box. when you can not specify any groups in grid then Global check box is automatically checked.

Comment: its showing pop message like should select any one access rights